# Should I edit an answer to re-do equations on a migrated question?

Tags: discussion, migration

The other day I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620694/how-to-translate-a-mathematically-described-algorithm-to-a-programming-language/22620695#22620695) on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) that was subsequently migrated to Stack Overflow. The original answer used math notation (since that was the basis of the question) which got un-rendered when the question was migrated.

Should I re-do the math in my answer by pasting in rendered images or just leave it as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think it would improve your answer and you have some time to spare - go ahead! No-one can force you to do it though, but if the meaning of your answer get lost in translation, you might receive fewer upvotes or even some downvotes.